# Simple linear algebra question

Tags: linear-algebra

**UPDATE:**

**TEXTBOOK IS WRONG. MMA ALWAYS CORRECT.**

***TEXT: An Introduction to Linear Algebra by kenneth Kuttler [Dec 17, 2003]***

I have a textbook example here:
[image: ex]

I tried the same in MMA and this was the result, what did I fail to understand in MMA here.

```
In[23]:= {1, 2, 1} + {5/3, 1/60, 1/60}

Out[23]= {8/3, 121/60, 61/60}
```

Is it the formatting?

Comment: No, your textbook is wrong.

Comment: Precisely the answer I was looking for ! Thanks !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too specific and it is unlikely that it will contribute to anyone but the OP.